# Github Actions - store context variable output

Tags: github-actions

I am new to github actions and I am trying to push multiple images to ECR and access it from ECS. Here is my workflow:

```
- name: Build and push the images
        run: |
          for versionFilePath in $(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r ${{ github.sha }} ${{ github.event.before }} | grep "VERSION");
          do
            folder=${versionFilePath%"/VERSION"}
            IMAGE_NAME=${folder##*/}

            tmpName="image-$RANDOM"
            docker build $folder --file $folder/Dockerfile --tag $tmpName
            IMAGE_ID=${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL }}/${{ secrets.REPOSITORY }}/$IMAGE_NAME
            VERSION=$(cat $versionFilePath)

            echo IMAGE_ID=$IMAGE_ID
            echo VERSION=$VERSION

            docker tag $tmpName $IMAGE_ID:$VERSION
            docker push $IMAGE_ID:$VERSION
          done;
- name: Download task definition
  run: |
    aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition service \
    --query taskDefinition > task-definition.json

- name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition
  id: task-def
  uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
  with:
    task-definition: task-definition.json
    container-name: application
    image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}

- name: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition
  uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1
  with:
    task-definition: ${{ steps.task-def.outputs.task-definition }}
    service: ${{ secrets.ECS_SERVICE }}
    cluster: ${{ secrets.ECS_CLUSTER }}
    wait-for-service-stability: true
```

I am able to build the images successfully. However, when multiple images are built, the ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }} gets only the name of the image that was last built. Is it possible to store the output in an array?

Answer (score 0):

From [`aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition` issues 72](https://github.com/aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition/issues/72), this would not be supported at the moment within the same task.

The [README](https://github.com/aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition#usage) mentions:

> If your task definition file holds multiple containers in the `containerDefinitions` section which require updated image URIs, chain multiple executions of this action together using the output value from the first action for the `task-definition` input of the second

So right now, that action would only consider one image name, not multiple (within a given task).

Comment: Here's one way I figured to append the image names to a .txt file. At the end of `Build and push the images`, inside the for loop before done, Im writing the image name to a txt file by doing `nameofimage >> container_name.txt`. This would still be tricky, since looping through this file during the `task-def` id step would be kinda hard. Any idea how to access that file during that step?

Comment: @boomchickawawa I missed your earlier comment but I agree. Looping it required. You can also [pass value between steps](https://www.ackama.com/what-we-think/values-github-actions/). And/Or [using a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70716837/6309).