# Is it possible to loop a Github Actions step?

Tags: github-actions

I have a Github Actions workflow dealing with new releases. Some last steps build the application for different platforms. Instead of creating multiple steps where each one builds for a different platform or creating a step running multiple commands I'm looking for a way to loop a step for each item in an array.

I know there is a matrix for jobs so this is my pseudo implementation to show what I'm looking for

```
jobs:
  do_it:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: For each entry in the array...
        strategy:
          matrix:
            target: [ this, that, something ]
        run: echo ${{ matrix.target }}
```

Is it possible to create something similiar to a matrix so it will loop the step multiple times?

As a sidenote, I know there is a similiar question [Using an array of values to repeat a step in GitHub Actions workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59180385/using-an-array-of-values-to-repeat-a-step-in-github-actions-workflow) but I don't want to split the job into multiple jobs because then I have to deal with all the build artifacts.